# How to add my UserControl from another project (Dll) into my WPF Solution?

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, user-controls

So, everything is in the title, I just want to add a UserControl in my WPF Window. It looks like easy but the UserControl is in another project (Dll project) in the same solution. And I just can't reference it.

So, my best try is something like that:

```
<Window xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyWindowProject" x:Name="window"
    xmlns:other="clr-namespace:MyDllProject"
    x:Class="MyWindowProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
>
    <other:MyUserControl />
</Window>
```

I know I am near to find how to make it because I've got just one error and the autocompletion is working on MyUserControl. But, I've got this weird error: "The name 'MyUserControl' does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MyDllProject".

I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong, but I really don't know what...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
xmlns:other="clr-namespace:MyDllProject"
```

The above import statement show's that you are pointing the namespace of your local project. if you want to add a refrance of the other project (The Dll Project)  then you must add the namespace as like

```
xmlns:other="clr-namespace:MyDllProjectNamespace;assembly=MyDllProject"
```

This will point the namespace which exists in Other assembly.

See this [Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to understand the namespaceing in Xaml

**Condition** Make sure the using control is accessible from the other assemblies.

Comment: Thank you for the article and your explanation. That will help me in the future.

Comment: It should be xmlns:other="clr-namespace:MyDllProjectNamespace;assembly=MyDllProject"  the 'a' in Assembly should be lowercase

Answer (score 1):

Add your user control to the controls tool box, and drag'n drop from there to your form. Visual Studio will take care of namespaces and things like that.

Comment: Thank you very much. Simple and easy to follow.

Answer (score -1):

Add the dll reference to your project.
Post that add the namespace of this  usercontrol to your xaml

say xmlns:local="... dll path;assembly=...."

Now the user control will be accessible in your xaml