# Adding UserControl from another project in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I created a WPF UserControl in a VisualStudio project, and now want to use it within another project.
I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17423176/12913162) how can i link in `xaml` this, but somehow, even after rebuilding several times, the compiler stills complains about `Assembly xxx not found`. What am i doing wrong?

My UserControl is inside project `CircularProgress` directly under the root (there's no extra folder) and has the name `CircularProgressControl.xaml`, and my new project xaml looks uses this

```
xmlns:other="clr-namespace:CircularProgress;assembly=CircularProgress"
...
<other:CircularProgressControl/>
```

[Here is a screenshot of my folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cn8t1.png)

Comment: Add a reference to CircularProcess to the CircularProcess_Test project.

Comment: I already did as explained in the question: `xmlns:other="clr-namespace:CircularProgress;assembly=CircularProgress"`, is it wrong or should i still do something else?

Comment: That's not an assembly reference. Open the context menu on the References folder of the project, then choose *Add Reference... -> Projects*

Comment: Thanks, that was what i required... please put it as an answer so that i can grant it!