# How to get custom property on MainWindow into a UserControl (from UserControl library/DLL)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, user-controls

I have a set of `UserControl`s in a library, but because the library is in a different namespace than the `MainWindow`, I don't seem to be able to get one `UserControl` to retrieve `List<features>` from `MainWindow`.

I suspect this is because `UserControl` does not know of `MainWindow`, and it's not meant to, as it is in a DLL library. As the `UserControl` is in a DLL, it should be agnostic to namespaces, but still be able to get what it needs.

So below I put some XAML and relative C# code-behind where you can see on the `UserControl`s `ListBox`, I'm trying to retrieve the `features` list from `MainWindow`.

```
<UserControl x:Class="FlatControls.MyListBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FlatControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="34" d:DesignWidth="100" MaxHeight="34" MaxWidth="100" x:Name="root">
   <ListBox x:Name="listBox">
</UserControl>
```

```
public MyListBox()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   listBox.Items = ???????????
}
```

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
        xmlns:FC="clr-namespace:FlatControls;assembly=FlatControls"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="1000" Width="1900" WindowState="Maximized" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant">
   <Grid>
      xyz
   </Grid>
<Window>
```

```
namespace MyApp
{
   public List<string> features = new List<string>();

   public MainWindow()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      features.Add("Concave");
      features.Add("Convex");
   }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, whether it's via Binding, or code-behind  :D

Comment: I don't know what is the exact problem in your code but there is already a similar problem and a verified solution is available in stackoverflow. Please check the link: [Similar Solution Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17422940/how-to-add-my-usercontrol-from-another-project-dll-into-my-wpf-solution)

Comment: I had a look, unfortunately this informs the MainWindow that it can use the DLL, but the DLL is still not aware of MainWindow. I could add a similar reference to the UserControl to be able to point to the MainWindow, but that would make the UserControl not re-usable on other projects.

Answer (score 0):

The `ListBox` in your custom `UserControl` has to bind its `ItemsSource` from somewhere. You should create an `ItemsSource` dependency property in your `MyListBox` to enable binding a collection from outside.

```
public partial class MyListBox : UserControl
{
   public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      nameof(ItemsSource), typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(MyListBox), new PropertyMetadata());

   public IEnumerable ItemsSource
   {
      get => (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
      set => SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
   }

   public MyListBox()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }
}
```

In the markup for the `MyListBox` user control, bind to this property using a `RelativeSource` binding.

```
<UserControl x:Class="FlatControls.MyListBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FlatControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="34" d:DesignWidth="100" MaxHeight="34" MaxWidth="100" x:Name="root">
   <ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyListBox}}}"/>
</UserControl>
```

Now, in your `MainWindow` use the control (you already added the corresponding XML namespace).

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
        xmlns:FC="clr-namespace:FlatControls;assembly=FlatControls"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="1000" Width="1900" WindowState="Maximized" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant">
    <Grid>
       <FC:MyListBox x:Name="MyListBox"/>
    </Grid>
<Window>
```

Finally, assign the `ItemsSource` property of the `MyListBox` control with the `features` collection.

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   features.Add("Concave");
   features.Add("Convex");

   MyListBox.ItemsSource = Features;
}
```

Alternatively, expose a property `Features` for your items and bind it in XAML.

```
public List<string> Features { get; }
```

```
<FC:MyListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Features}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @thatguy said, you can use his way to do.
Of course, if you like to write code in view.cs, you can use "FieldModifier" word to decorade you listbox in your MyListBox:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" x:FieldModifier="public" />
```

And in your MainWindow, you can get the listbox instance, of cource, you can set its itemsource like this:

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.userControl.listBox.ItemsSource = new List<string>() { "11","22","33"};
    }
```